# Why was my forex question off topic, when other similar questions weren't?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

For reference, my question: [What happens on foreign exchange markets when a currency ends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66517/what-happens-on-foreign-exchange-markets-when-a-currency-ends/66518#66518)

Other questions not marked as off-topic:

- [FOREX: Pair Trading, What is Really Happening?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15712/forex-pair-trading-what-is-really-happening?rq=1)
- [Currency exchange problem](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26341/currency-exchange-problem?rq=1)
- [How does the fluctuation in the foreign exchange market occur at the same time in all countries?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26674/how-does-the-fluctuation-in-the-foreign-exchange-market-occur-at-the-same-time-i?rq=1)

I feel it *is* a personal finance question, because people could have serious repercussions due to a currency collapse, and I was looking for some sort of historical reference as to what happens. I even got an adequate answer, making this more confusing.

Comment: Getting a good answer does not necessarily imply that the question was on topic. You asked a general economic theory question; that is out of scope and belongs on the economics stack.

Comment: I wasn't asking about economic theory or general impacts. I'm asking what literally happens when a currency collapses? As in, what does the exchange rate become? Do the forex trading services cut things off, etc. I'm not asking for someone's opinion on what likely outcomes are to the economy of a nation.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. One of the issues may be the hypothetical nature of the question. From the [help section](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Members may have felt your question did not fit this. The questions you linked were all answerable currently. Keep in mind, SE is member-run, 5 members voted to close your question, and so far, only one has visited here to reply.

Answer (score 9):

The question you asked is a broad level economic and politics question. It is hypothetical as to what happens to Euro. Well it would depend on politics ... There was no Euro 15 years back. What happened to all the older currencies, there was a negotiated period, the rates were pegged initially and the over a period of time the older currencies were withdrawn once everything got denominated to Euros. Similarly if Euro is no longer around, it can't happen all of sudden.

What exactly would happen is more speculative and multiple things can happen and each option would be thought of before an option is selected.

A generic currency collapse is an Economic question. In past some currencies have reached that point and every-time something else has happened. Its to that extent unpredictable.